# How to avoid a forced shutdown or crash when the MagSafe is plugged in and got loose?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, power-management, magsafe

The new MagSafe for the current Macbook Air isn't very strong for its magnetic force, so it can become loose easily.  Today I left the Macbook Air unplugged and it went into sleep, and after I plugged in the MagSafe and moved the Macbook Air 2, 3 feet, the MagSafe became loose again, while the computer is "wakening from sleep", and I immediately plugged in the MagSafe but the computer seemed to "go to sleep right away".

At this point, when I press the Power button, it won't start up.  I pressed it for 2 seconds, 3 seconds, and it won't start up.  I waited for 30 seconds and tried, and then 1 minute and tried and it won't start up.  I had to press the Power button for 5, 6 seconds or more, and then it rebooted.  So the OS, all the apps were stopped abruptly as if it were a power outage.  I really doesn't hope that it would happen, as any app that created temporary cache files won't get cleaned up, and will waste the hard drive space, and in general I just don't like the computer being shut down this way, as if the power plug is just pulled like on a desktop computer.

Is there a way to avoid this, or maybe the OS can be fixed so that it won't "wake up and go to sleep right away and crash".  One possibility I can think of is set the computer to sleep not when the power is at 1% or 2%, but at 3% or 5%, and somehow set the computer not to sleep right away once it got waken up, at least for a minute, if the user plugs in the MagSafe and it became loose for a few second seconds again.

(one way is just to make sure after the MagSafe is plugged in, it won't got loose for at least for 1, 2, or a few minutes, so that if the MagSafe became loose, the power already got increased so the computer won't to sleep, or even if it goes to sleep, it has enough power to do so, so that the whole system won't crash.  But it would be better if the computer can handle it even when the user doesn't take this extra precaution.)

Answer (score 1):

If the battery is drained and you cut the power source, it effectively is a power outage. The only way to avoid this is by not disconnecting the charger while the battery is empty, or by not letting the battery drain completely.

Comment: no, it is not an outage. The computer went into hibernation, so if I plug in the MagSafe and press the Power button, it will wake from the hibernation